# Sorting dictionary by key - unpack error

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the keys contain timestamps. Basically I want to sort the dictionary on that timestamp; so I can fetch that dictionary value that corresponds to the "first" timestamp.

I tried:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime

def _fetch_ts(name):
    return datetime.strptime(name[-13:], '%Y%m%d_%H%M')

incoming_dict = {'20170410_1133': 'A', '20170412_1133': 'B'}
print("starting with: {}".format(incoming_dict))
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(incoming_dict, key=_fetch_ts))
print("gives        : {}".format(incoming_dict))
print("should be A or B: {}".format(sorted_dict.values()[0]))
```

But that prints

```
starting with: {'20170410_1133': 'A', '20170412_1133': 'B'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(incoming_dict, key=_fetch_ts))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You sort dictionary keys, instead of key-value pairs. Use `sorted(incoming_dict.items(), ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use incoming_dict.items() to unpack the value pairs from incoming_dict.

```
OrderedDict(sorted(incoming_dict.items(), key=_fetch_ts))
```

As mentioned, you'll need to modify `_fetch_ts` as well, however you can easily just reference `name[0][-13:]`.

Comment: You'll need to change `_fetch_ts` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebuild the OrderedDict by sorting it in advance and rebuilding it as an list of tuples.

like:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime

def _fetch_ts(name):
    val = datetime.strptime(name[-13:], '%Y%m%d_%H%M')
    return val

incoming_dict = {'20170410_1133': 'A', '20170412_1133': 'B'}
print("starting with: {}".format(incoming_dict))
print(sorted(incoming_dict, key=_fetch_ts))
sorted_dict = OrderedDict([(x,incoming_dict[x]) for x in sorted(incoming_dict, key=_fetch_ts)])
print("gives        : {}".format(incoming_dict))
print("should be A or B: {}".format(sorted_dict.values()[0]))
```

Comment: That is a nice detail. But I think I go with the first solution; I find that a bit more readable.